# Where are the files stored on cloudhub

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, cloudhub, anypoint-platform

Per my understanding, cloudhub is a PaaS service and we can deploy applications directly to Cloudhub. I have below questions

1. Can we create intermediate files on cloudhub. If yes, how can we define the path ?
2. When we use SFTP to pull file from particular location, what should be the path on cloudhub server for processing
3. Can we do SSH on cloudhub server
4. If we need to externalize cron timings of scheduler ,(via config etc to avoid code change) , what is the best practice for setting cron expression.

All above questions are related to Cloudhub deployment model.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

- The scheduler already gets externalized in the platform when you deploy to CloudHub.
- You can technically store the files in `/temp`, but don't expect them to persist. That would be an "ephemeral" file system.
- You can not SSH into the CloudHub server.
- Rather than downloading the entire SFTP file and saving it, and then working on it, I would suggest streaming it if possible. You can process JSON/XML/CSV files as a stream, and even use deferred DataWeave with them enabling end-to-end streaming.

Comment: regarding the  last point : do u mean we can stream the file directly from SFTP location itself ?

Comment: Yes. You can work on the file as the chunks are downloaded, aka streaming.